# Why is the output shape (3,2,32,64) when I convolve my (3,3,64,64) input with another (3,3,64,64) input using tf.nn.conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow's tf.nn.conv2d to convolve a (3,3,64,64) input with a (3,3,64,64) filter using stride 2 and SAME padding. I was expecting the output shape to be (2,2,64,64), but I'm getting (3,2,32,64) instead. I think using stride 2 seems to be the cause but I'm not exactly sure why it's outputting the shape (3,2,32,64). Anyone familiar with this know why this is happening? Is this an issue with the stride, padding, or data format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the expected input format for tf.nn.conv2d is (size, h, w, in_channel) when I was using (h, w, in_channel, size). To get my desired output shape (2,2,64,64), I can use tf.transpose to change the format of my input, convolve, and then transpose my output back to the original format:

```
input = tf.transpose(input, perm=(3, 0, 1, 2))
output = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=2, padding='SAME')
output = tf.transpose(output, perm=(1, 2, 3, 0))
```